# When I installed coc completion on neovim, Then I open nvim as usual and see this error

Tags: autocomplete, neovim

This error is

```
[coc.nvim] build/index.js not found, please install dependencies and compile coc.nvim by: yarn install
```

any help ? :< I just love using neovim but it just sucks like this

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information. What operating system are you using? May you share your configuration files so we can understand your situation better?

Perhaps this GitHub issue may help? https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/issues/3258

A temporary fix could be done through the following shell commands:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/coc.nvim   # the path might different depending on the plugin manager you use
git checkout release
```

For the prebuilt package, you need to change to the release branch, in the package manager part of your configuration.